# How to change field name in raster file?

Tags: raster, geoserver, gdal, wms

I´m having a bit of an understanding problem with a DEM TIF file.  I have a DEM TIF file which is served with Geoserver.  When I click on the layer the WMSGetFeatureInfo gives me the following output:

GREY_INDEX
110.0

I realise that the 110.0 is the height, but what I don´t understand is why the raster field is called grey_index. The DGM was produced from a point shapefile which was then interpolated using spatialanalyst. The height field in the shapefile was called "z" so why is this then converted to "grey_index"?

For the WMSGetFeatureInfo I would like to change the field name to "Height" but how do I do this? Is this really a "Field" in the same sense as a shapefile dbf? Am I able to just change field names in raster files?

I have GDAL and ESRI libraries available if anyone can help.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the third pixel value is set as axisName in the info.xml file that can be found from data_dir/coverages/[coverage name]. Edit it, save and reload the configuration.

```
 <axisName>GRAY_INDEX</axisName>
```